# Trouble creating library package

Tags: package-management

I am having some trouble creating a package for a shared library.

I ran `dh_make` and edited the files. However, when I go to build the package, I get the following:

```
******@******-laptop:~/Documents/temp/jsoncpp/jsoncpp-0.5.0$ debuild
 dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -D -us -uc
dpkg-buildpackage: set CFLAGS to default value: -g -O2
dpkg-buildpackage: set CPPFLAGS to default value: 
dpkg-buildpackage: set LDFLAGS to default value: -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions
dpkg-buildpackage: set FFLAGS to default value: -g -O2
dpkg-buildpackage: set CXXFLAGS to default value: -g -O2
dpkg-buildpackage: source package jsoncpp
dpkg-buildpackage: source version 0.5.0-1
dpkg-buildpackage: source changed by ****** 
dpkg-buildpackage: host architecture amd64
 fakeroot debian/rules clean
dh  clean
   dh_testdir
   dh_auto_clean
   dh_clean
 dpkg-source -b jsoncpp-0.5.0
dpkg-source: info: using source format `1.0'
dpkg-source: info: building jsoncpp using existing jsoncpp_0.5.0.orig.tar.gz
dpkg-source: info: building jsoncpp in jsoncpp_0.5.0-1.diff.gz
dpkg-source: info: building jsoncpp in jsoncpp_0.5.0-1.dsc
 debian/rules build
dh  build
   dh_testdir
   dh_auto_configure
   dh_auto_build
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/******/Documents/temp/jsoncpp/jsoncpp-0.5.0'
test -d obj || mkdir obj
g++ -I ./include -c -o obj/json_reader.o src/lib_json/json_reader.cpp
g++ -I ./include -c -o obj/json_writer.o src/lib_json/json_writer.cpp
g++ -I ./include -c -o obj/json_value.o src/lib_json/json_value.cpp
ar -r libjsoncpp.a obj/json_reader.o obj/json_writer.o obj/json_value.o
ar: creating libjsoncpp.a
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/******/Documents/temp/jsoncpp/jsoncpp-0.5.0'
   dh_auto_test
 fakeroot debian/rules binary
dh  binary
   dh_testroot
   dh_prep
   dh_installdirs
   dh_auto_install
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/******/Documents/temp/jsoncpp/jsoncpp-0.5.0'
sudo cp -r include/json --target-directory=/usr/include
ERROR: ld.so: object 'libfakeroot-sysv.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded: ignored.
cp libjsoncpp.a /usr/lib/libjsoncpp.a
cp: cannot create regular file `/usr/lib/libjsoncpp.a': Permission denied
make[1]: *** [install] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/******/Documents/temp/jsoncpp/jsoncpp-0.5.0'
dh_auto_install: make -j1 install DESTDIR=/home/******/Documents/temp/jsoncpp/jsoncpp-0.5.0/debian/tmp returned exit code 2
make: *** [binary] Error 29
dpkg-buildpackage: error: fakeroot debian/rules binary gave error exit status 2
debuild: fatal error at line 1340:
dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -D -us -uc failed
```

The problem seems to be here:

> ERROR: ld.so: object 'libfakeroot-sysv.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded: ignored.
>   cp libjsoncpp.a /usr/lib/libjsoncpp.a
>   cp: cannot create regular file `/usr/lib/libjsoncpp.a': Permission denied

...but I haven't the faintest idea what the problem is.

The makefile is [here](http://pastebin.com/K6frvDeR) if needed.

Comment: Are you sure you have all the build-prerequisites installed?

Comment: @txwikinger: No... how can I be sure? (Sorry, I'm new to package building - I've only ever built one and it wasn't a library.)

Comment: Did you get the source upstream or from apt-get source?

Comment: @txwikinger: Well, I got the source upstream but needed to modify it quite heavily to insert a Makefile and remove unnecessary files. Probably I shouldn't have done it that way, but I don't know any better way. By the way, the package is [jsoncpp](http://jsoncpp.sf.net).

Comment: Maybe offtopic to this question, but in general we do not edit the sources, we create patches for any changes. However, this would probably not have a baring on this problem.

Comment: Try running it in pbuilder. It might be it is just a permission problem, since dh_auto_install tries to install something for which you need to be root.

Comment: George, I'm not a package builder, but just looking at that error, `cp: cannot create regular file '/usr/lib/libjsoncpp.a': Permission denied`, I wonder if it would help to run as root.

Comment: @mac: Well, this is happening inside of `fakeroot` if I'm not mistaken, so there should not be any permission problems.

Comment: @txwikinger: Sorry, I tried `pbuilder` but I don't know what commands to use. I tried `pbuilder --help` but couldn't find anything.

Comment: @George: Have a look here: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PbuilderHowto

Comment: @txwikinger: Okay, thanks. I'm building the chroot environment right now... might take a few minutes :)

Comment: @txwikinger: Uhm... I'm running pbuilder and it's asking for a password. What should I do? My root password doesn't seem to work.

Comment: it needs your user password like if you do sudo

Comment: @txwikinger: It didn't work either. I think the problem might be with my makefile. The `install` target requires root priv. When I run `debuild`, it complains about not having permission to copy to `/usr/lib/`, etc. I stuck `sudo` in front of the appropriate lines in the makefile, and now I get the error: `"dh_install: jsoncpp-dev missing files (usr/include/*), aborting"`. Where did this error come from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Makefile you are using is not respecting the DESTDIR variable - packages should never install directly into /usr at build time, but instead put files into a temporary tree.
You've mentioned that you added the Makefile yourself - the usual case is that you'd need to make it use the DESTDIR variable as a prefix for all install paths.
Having looked at the package build instructions, the package uses scons as a build system, which is a replacement of sorts for make. dh_make most likely doesn't have a template for building packages with this, so you should look for packages that do use it for building, such as yafray, and look at their debian/rules

As package builds are never done as root, it is better to have this error shown & corrected rather than having a package overwrite important files as the package is being built on an unsuspecting developer's system.

Comment: Aha! Thank you soooo much! This piece of information is a tremendous help.

Answer (score 0):

As you figured the problems lies here:

```
cp libjsoncpp.a /usr/lib/libjsoncpp.a
```

You are calling `debbuild` as normal user, who has no rights to write to that directory. If you try `sudo debbuild` it should work.

Comment: This does not fix the problem. As mentioned above, this is happening inside a chroot environment... so permissions should not be a problem.